# How to schedule auto hibernation and wake up

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, hibernate, scheduled-tasks

I leave my laptop running 24/7 because it does some tasks in the background 24/7. However, I want to turn shutdown my laptop for 2 hours every day. Unfortunately my bios does not support scheduled power ups. Thus I cannot create a scheduled task to shut down my laptop.

I have decided the best best alternative may be to schedule my computer to hibernate for 2 hours. However, I am unclear how to schedule the computer to hibernate and how to wake it up. All the tutorials I have found as to shut the computer down.

Currently there is no password to log into my windows 10 laptop. Could someone tell me how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: The plain Windows 10 solution: https://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/ (a bit complicated for a 2h nap). May be there is a solution to automate this via a powershell script based on this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-scheduled-tasks/.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to achive it with on board utilities? If not you can just use a third party tool, for example [WakeupOnStandBy](https://dennisbabkin.com/wosb/) or [some other tools](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/automatically-wake-up-from-windows-stand-by-and-hibernation/)

Personally I like analog: I would buy an old fashioned alarm clock (the one with the bells), put it on top of my mouse and enable "wake on USB" ;)

If you want on board utilities you could use [Wake Timers](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/63070-enable-disable-wake-timers-windows-10-a.html), you can enable them (for example) through your power options:

[image]